# What is the best practice for creating a module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen this done two ways:

1. The `module` is assigned a global variable which is then appended to directives, controllers, and services:

   ```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', [ ]);

   app.directive('myDirective' function() {
      // directive stuff here
   });
   ```
2. Or the the module is used as-is like:

   ```
   angular.module('myApp', [ ])

   .directive('myDirective' function() {
      // directive stuff here
   });
   ```

So why would you do it one way or the other?

Comment: I'm really surprised the duplicate didn't show up when you typed in your title.

Comment: hmmm.. me as well. Thanks for that!

Comment: Readability-wise, #1 looks better to me.  Chaining periods together (`angular.module().directive`) can get hard to read and violates the "law of demeter" that Misko Hevery talks about (Misko is the original angularjs author)

Comment: @ZackMacomber popular style guides recommend the second approach using `module()` as getter. Components don't have to be chained, you can use a getter anywhere